# Printing Table with hidden rows using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a client side paginated table.
Now I need to print this table using pure Javascript.

the tablename id is tablepaging and a div(#tableContainer ) is holding the table

Now I set the options in print.css as below

```
    <style> 
@media print
{
     @page {size: landscape}
     #tableContainer {height:100% ;}
     #tablepaging{height:100% ;}
     #tablepaging tr{display:block;}
    }  
</style>
```

However it is not printing the hidden rows in the table. I want the entire content of the table to be printed

Comment: Can you please post the full html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add following instead of display block:

```
@media print
{
     @page {size: landscape}
     #tableContainer {height:100% ;}
     #tablepaging{height:100% ;}
     #tablepaging tr{display: table-row !important;}
}
```

Comment: Why @page {size: landscape} doesnt't work with IE8 but works fine with Chrome. How can I fix this in IE8

Comment: Well, there is no phone with IE8 so I'm not sure what would you need landscape query for that browser. You can always use : @media print and (max-width: xxx px) and put the width for landscape dimension you are targeting..